# Installing homebrew after upgrading to MacOS High Sierra

Tags: terminal, high-sierra, install, homebrew

Recently I upgraded to MacOS High Sierra (10.13.4). After upgrade my homebrew seems to have stopped working. So I uninstalled the homebrew by executing the below command

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

I tried to install homebrew again by executing the below command

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

But the installation failed with the error as discussed [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/2062).

Then I tried executing the command as suggested in the above issue.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local
```

But it did not work because of the issue discussed [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3228).

I executed the below command as suggested above

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

It gave me some `Operation not permitted` warnings.

Then I again tried to install homebrew. Now it is showing me the below logs in console

```
...
==> Installation successful!

==> Homebrew has enabled anonymous aggregate user behaviour analytics.
Read the analytics documentation (and how to opt-out) here:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Analytics.html

==> Next steps:
- Run `brew help` to get started
- Further documentation:
    https://docs.brew.sh
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 504, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Can some one let me know what does the last set of warnings / errors denote? Can these be ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning at the end is telling you that the `root` user (denoted by default with the uid `0`) doesn't own the `/etc/sudoers` file anymore. This is bad. At some point you may have accidentally changed this, perhaps by mistyping a command. The `sudoers` file denotes which users and groups are allowed to escalate to a root privilege set by prefacing a command with `sudo` and typing their login password.

The `chown` command you've been using above changes the ownership of files from one user and/or group to another. Because you've changed ownership of the `sudoers` file you probably won't be able to `sudo` yourself out of trouble as the `sudo` command won't run for security reasons if the `sudoers` file from which it draws its configuration is owned by a user other than `root` (this is why homebrew is spitting out the last error message above).

I'd suggest the following:

1. Enable the root user using Apple's instructions [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012) (under the section 'Enable or disable the root user').
2. Open Terminal and switch to the root user by typing `su -` and entering the password you assigned to your root user account in step 1.
3. As the root user, change ownership of the `sudoers` file back to root and the wheel group with the following:

   ```
   chown root:wheel /etc/passwd
   ```
4. Follow the instructions in step 1 again but this time *disable* the root user again.

You should now be able to use the `sudo` command again with your regular admin user. You can run `sudo ls` for instance in a new shell; if the contents of the current directory are listed and you don't see that ownership error above then all is well.

Although this falls outside the bounds of your question, I'm concerned that if you've unwittingly changed ownership of the `sudoers` file while attempting to change ownership of `/usr/local/` you may have done this to other important files as well. Run `ls -l /etc/` and examine the output of that command. The third column in from the left shows the user who owns a given file. By default, pretty much every file in the `/etc/` directory is meant to be owned by root (an obvious one is `/etc/passwd`). If you see the majority are owned by another user (your own username for instance), the problem is far more extensive than your `sudoers` file.

As a general point, you need to be very careful running any command prefaced by `sudo`. Only run commands in your terminal if you understand the command and know exactly what it will do when passed a given set of options/arguments. There are some safeguards provided by the more recent Mac operating systems with [System Integrity Protection (SIP)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) but you can still wreak plenty of havoc on your system.

If you want to learn what a particular command and its various arguments do, try checking the manual first by typing `man` + the command you want information on (`man sudo` or `man chown` for example).

Answer (score 1):

Just went through this process myself. The installation command (slightly different in 2021) on the homebrew site  did not work for the same reason you posted.

I came across the same suggested command

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

After running it, I started seeing tons of permissions errors being logged. It took me about an entire minute to realize what was going on and hit ctrl+c, and why the suggested command is actually **a bad idea for initial setup**.

Since brew isnt installed yet (not on the PATH), then `$(brew --prefix)` evaluates to null/blank.

In other words `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*` is actually running `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /*` which is bad.

For anyone else trying to do setup on a new machine, I ended up having to setup homebrew under my user directory even though it's "not recommended"

https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/664d0c67d5947605c914c4c56ebcfaa80cb6eca0/docs/Installation.md#untar-anywhere

```
cd ~

mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

then add ~/homebrew/bin to PATH